# overflow-x:visible css property doesnt work

Tags: overflow

i have a vertical menu in my web page i gave a specific height to the container div of menu. I tried to scroll only the vertical overflow not the horizontal scroll but when I hover on menu item it shows horizontal scroll instead of showing the submenu.

My css is below

```
    .navdiv{
     overflow-y:scroll;
     height:380px;
     overflow-x:visible;
    }
```

I tried all variations of overflow-x but to no avail